# Guardar archivos .csv en un formato peronalizado de archivos en VB.net

Tags: vb.net, xml, csv, vb

espero tengan buen día.

He estado intentando crear una nueva extensión de archivo para almacenar una serie de documentos de formato .csv, el concepto que tengo es como si ese archivo de nueva extensión fuera la creación de un proyecto (.proj) y dentro de este se almacenen archivos que correspondan a este mismo proyectos, para organizar más los documentos que se están utilizando. Algo así como lo que puede hacer LabVIEW con sus archivos .lvproj y se almacenen los .vi que correspondan a ese proyecto.

He estado viendo que es posible realizarlo con ayuda de XML, pero aún no encuentro la manera correcta de realziarlo, no es como un tema sencillo de encontrar por internet o quizá no lo estoy buscando de la manera correcta.

Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El .csv es un simple archivo de texto generalmente delimitado por comas, asi que si a ese archivo le cambias la extensión, no le pasa absolutamente nada al contenido por que le puedes poner MiArchivo.aaa y aun lo podrás abrir con bloc de notas por lo tanto, desde tu programa, lo puedes abrir como fichero y leer el contenido.
Tu quieres generar un tipo de archivo de proyecto y que este archivo a su vez tenga archivos asociados, la verdad solo se me ocurre que cada proyecto tenga su propia carpeta, así, tu archivo de proyecto, buscaría dentro del mismo directorio los archivos con tu extensión personalizada, pero yo pondría al inicio del archivo, ósea en la primera línea del archivo, el nombre del proyecto al que esta relacionado y debajo del nombre, todo el contenido que va a leer el programa, también se me ocurre que, en tu archivo proyecto, escribas los nombres de los archivos que corresponden al mismo y así verificar si falta alguno.